# Getting a 2-D list and adding each column

Tags: list, python-2.7, matrix

I'm trying to create a function where a user inputs the values for a 3x4 2-D list, then the function prints the grid of numbers, along with an extra row at the bottom with the sum of each column. At the moment, I can't even get it to take any inputs without getting errors. Here's what I've got so far, without the addition of the columns at the end.

```
def testMatrixFunctions():
row0 = raw_input("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 0: ")
row0.split()
map(float, row0.split())
[float(c) for c in row0.split()]
row1 = raw_input("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 1: ")
row1.split()
map(float, row1.split())
[float(c) for c in row1.split()]
row2 = raw_input("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 2: ")
row2.split()
map(float, row2.split())
[float(c) for c in row2.split()]
print row0
print row1
print row2
```

Comment: You should supply a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing exactly what errors you're getting. However, I'm confused why you use `map()` to modify a list in-place, then give a list comprehension that doesn't assign to a variable. Can you explain exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I used the map function on the advice of someone else earlier. Long story. What I need is the input from the user to become a 2-D list that's 3x4. The function should then print the grid, and an extra row at the bottom that's the sum of the column above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to get the column sum

```
import sys
import numpy

ROWS = 3
COLS = 4

def main():

    global ROWS
    global COLS
    matrixData = []

    # Get input and process it
    for i in range(0, ROWS):
        thisRow = raw_input('Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row ' + str(i) + ' : ').split()
        evalRow = []
        [evalRow.append(eval(element)) for element in thisRow]      
        matrixData.append(evalRow)          

    numpyMatrix = numpy.array(matrixData)
    colSums = []
    [colSums.append(numpy.sum(numpyMatrix[:,index])) for index in range(0,COLS)]

    # Print the matrix
    for row in matrixData:
        print row
    print colSums
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```